# Правильно ли стоят запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

За всё существование Прованса дизайн значительно изменился, из аскетичного превратился в утонченный и стал пользоваться большой популярностью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

**За всё время существования стиля Прованс он  значительно изменился, из аскетичного превратился в утонченный и стал пользоваться большой популярностью.**

Возможные сочетания: стиль Прованс, дизайн интерьера Прованс, интерьер в стиле Прованс, стиль Прованс в интерьере и т. д.

**Примеры использования в тексте:**
[**Что такое стиль Прованс?**](http://www.muraveynik.com/faq/dizayn-interera-/chto-takoe-stil-provans_1384428370/)

Провансом называется область, расположенная на юге Франции. В ней есть потрясающие пейзажи... Из этих компонентов и состоит **стиль интерьера под названием Прованс.**

**Интерьер в стиле Прованс** – красивый, неброский, отдает стариной. **Стиль Прованс в жилом интерьере** – это использование натурального дерева, природного камня.

В современном дизайне интерьера **прованский стиль** приветствуется. Его применяют в кухнях, детских комнатах, столовых.

Но у всех регионов была единая особенность – это воспевание легкости, невесомости во всем.  Она стала для **стиля Прованс в дизайне интерьера** особенной.  Легкостью обозначались разные достижения Франции, она повлияла на изобразительное искусство, музыку, и потом перенеслась **в дизайн интерьера** Прованс.